How to extract drawn areas from Bitmap in Android?
I'm working on an Android app using Kotlin where users can draw paths (lines or curves) on images using Canvas. The goal is to extract only painted areas from the original image, while unpainted areas should be transparent.
However, the result I get shows wrong, The resulting image does not extract a bitmap drawn with colored lines, but rather extracts an entire delineated area.
Can anyone give me a solution? Thanks in advance.
Here is my current code for extracting the painted region:
class CustomImageView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : ImageView(context, attrs) {
private val path = Path()
private val paint = Paint().apply {
    color = Color.RED
    style = Paint.Style.STROKE
    strokeWidth = 8f
}
private var drawCanvas: Canvas? = null
private lateinit var drawingBitmap: Bitmap

init {
    setOnTouchListener { _, event ->
        when (event.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                path.moveTo(event.x, event.y)
                true
            }

            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                path.lineTo(event.x, event.y)
                invalidate()
                true
            }

            else -> false
        }
    }
}

override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas)
    drawCanvas = canvas
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint)
}


fun getMaskedBitmap(originalBitmap: Bitmap): Bitmap {
    val width = originalBitmap.width
    val height = originalBitmap.height

    val maskedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    val canvas = Canvas(maskedBitmap)

    canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)

    val maskPaint = Paint().apply {
        style = Paint.Style.FILL
        color = Color.BLACK
        isAntiAlias = true
    }

    canvas.drawPath(path, maskPaint)

    val imagePaint = Paint().apply {
        xfermode = PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
    }

    canvas.drawBitmap(originalBitmap, 0f, 0f, imagePaint)

    return maskedBitmap
}

}
This is error result after drawn

The sunflower image below is the result I want after drawing, the part of the image not drawn by the red line will disappear:



You should clarify what you mean by "extract delineated area". As currently shown your image doesn't have complete loop of "red" . If the lower part of the image shows what you want to do, you need to complete the polygon, flood fill the polygon as a mask layer and porter-duff with the original image. If you are trying something else, please provide more details of what is and isn't happening.

there is to be no extracting. you should paint on a separate layer instead of the original image.

Thanks everyone for your comments, I added a sunflower image as an illustration of the result I wanted after drawing and creating a new image.

the android example suggests that you will have to keep track of all the strokes too. the hourglass shape only results from turning that Z-shaped line into a closed polygon. it cannot result from any operations at the raster graphic level.

The paint “maskPaint” should set “style = Paint.Style.STROKE” instead, just like your path paint.
